# PowerShell como administrador

Tags: powershell

**Hola, quisiera poder tener el PowerShell nativo de Windows 10 en el menú contextual
tal cual se muestra en la imagen**

```
                                                      ▼
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**pero por más que replique lo que hace el PowerShell 7 no pude
lograrlo, me refiero a editar el registro de windows pero nada pude hacer**
**ojala me pudieran ayudar**

Comment: ¿Existe el mismo problema con powershell versión 5?

Comment: No entendí tu pregunta 

Comment: Es posible que esto ayude. https://www.howtogeek.com/165268/how-to-add-open-powershell-here-to-the-context-menu-in-windows/

Comment: Pero también quiero agregarlo con la opción de administrador 

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago de esta manera. (Es un .reg) Lo importa al registro y crea el menú contextual.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PSCustomMenu] 
"Icon"="C:\\\\Windows\\\\system32\\\\WindowsPowerShell\\\\v1.0\\\\powershell.exe"
"MUIVerb"="PowerShell"
"SubCommands"=""


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PSCustomMenu\Shell\PS]
    @="Open here"
    "Icon"="C:\\\\Windows\\\\system32\\\\WindowsPowerShell\\\\v1.0\\\\powershell.exe"
    

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PSCustomMenu\Shell\PS\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -Command \"Start-Process C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe  -ArgumentList '-NoProfile', '-NoExit', '-Command Set-Location -LiteralPath %V'\""


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PSCustomMenu\Shell\PSAdmin]
    @="Open here as Administrator"
    "Icon"="C:\\\\Windows\\\\system32\\\\WindowsPowerShell\\\\v1.0\\\\powershell.exe,1"
    
    
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PSCustomMenu\Shell\PSAdmin\command]
@="C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden -Command \"Start-Process C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe  -ArgumentList '-NoProfile', '-NoExit', '-Command Set-Location -LiteralPath %V' -Verb runAs\""
```

Comment: Gracias bro lo voy a probar y ya te digo ....  

Comment: Me sirvió a medias https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/147645/dany

Answer (score -1):

### *Mira lo que me sale cuando lo ejecuto*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que no importaste correctamente el archivo .reg ¿como lo hiciste?